# Is this javascript loop still Async?

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, callback

I wrote this loop which I think is async.

Can anyone confirm if it is or not please?

It's 3 functions that call each other repeatedly until it runs out of iterations. When it finishes it calls a callback in the parent function.

```
function compareRightsLoop(rights, request, callback) {
    loopInit(request.length, 0, 0, loopIncrement);

    var loopInit = function(max, inc, boolIncr, initLoopIncrement) {
        if (rights.indexOf(request[inc]) === -1);
        else
          boolIncr++;
        initLoopIncrement(max, inc, boolIncr, this, loopTerminate);
    };

    var loopIncrement = function(max, inc, boolIncr, initLoopInit, initLoopTerminate) {
        inc++;
        if (max === inc)
          initLoopTerminate(max, inc, boolIncr);
        else
          initLoopInit(max, inc, boolIncr);
    };

    var loopTerminate = function(max, inc, boolIncr) {
        if (max == boolIncr)
          callback(true);
        else
          callback(false);
    };
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it's async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is synchronous.

All the functions you've created are sync, and there is nothing there turning your functions async.

The fact that you pass a callback function to them says nothing, as they don't execute something in the background, waiting for it to return or anything like that.

Your code is not even working, since you're trying to use the variables before declaring them.

And, if we suppose that you have defined the variables before trying to use them, even there, you wouldn't have async functions. If you debug the code, you will see that it enters inside each function and do the complete loop, before going to the next line of the code.

It would be async, for example, if you were calling with a `setTimeout`, like this:

```
var loopInit = function(max, inc, boolIncr, initLoopIncrement) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (rights.indexOf(request[inc]) === -1);
    else
      boolIncr++;
    initLoopIncrement(max, inc, boolIncr, this, loopTerminate);
  }, 0);
};
```

Comment: K thanks, i think i should have tested a little more before posting this question. It doesn't work indeed. Back to the drawing-board.